# Eclipse Juno Switch Editor in Order

Tags: macos, eclipse

In case it matters:

- OS: Mac OS X Lion (10.7.4)
- Eclipse: Juno, Build id: 20120614-1722

I have several files open in my eclipse workspace as tabs. The default shortcuts for previous and next editors are <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F6</kbd>. I know how to change these shortcuts, that's not the issue.

However, what I want to do, is switch between editors in the way in which they're ordered in the tab bar. Currently, the editors change in order of last used/viewed.

So, if I had three files (`A`, `B` and `C` in order) open and I'm currently editing `A` and I edited `B` last, when I use the shortcut for "Previous Editor", it takes me to `B` instead of `C` (and vice versa).

Is there any way for me to get this functionality out of eclipse (if so, how)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a solution to your problem. This is answered best by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2332440/198633) for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332330/eclipse-hotkey-how-to-switch-between-tabs).

Essentially, there are options in Eclipse called "Next Tab," and "Previous Tab" (in Preferences > General > Keys). These are the options to which a key combination should be bound, in order to pass to the next editor, or the previous editor.

Comment: I didn't know about the Next and Previous Tab options. I thought the eclipse lingo for "tab" was "editor". Thank you for clarifying